# NestJs TypeORM unable to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to connect to MySQL. I have defined the db connection vars in a .env file in my root dir, and I am initializing the connection in the `app.module.ts` file.
the only issue I am facing now is when creating or running migrations using the CLI,
I followed the typeorm docs [here](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations/creating-a-new-migration) to configure the connection, however when I run   `typeorm migrate:create -n myNewTable`, it should create the migration file in the specified directory, what it does instead is it creates it in the app root directory,
similarily, I solved the issue by using the `-d` flag after the `typeorm migrate:create` to specify the directory, however when I try running my migration files, I get this

> No connection options were found in any of configurations file.

here is my app.module.ts file.

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT, 10),
      username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
      synchronize: false,
      migrations: [process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS],
      cli: {
        migrationsDir: process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR,
      },
      logging: (process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING === 'true') ? true : false,
      entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    }),
```

and here is my .env file

```js
# use .ts for development, .js for production
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = mysql
TYPEORM_HOST = 127.0.0.1
TYPEORM_PORT = 3306
TYPEORM_USERNAME = <username>
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = <password>
TYPEORM_DATABASE = <dbname>
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = true
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONSRUN = true
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/**/**.entity.ts
#TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/**/**.entity.js
TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS = src/subscriber/*.ts
#TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS = src/subscriber/*.js
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = src/database/migration/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR = src/database/migration
TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS_DIR = src/subscriber
```

any help/hint is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @MoSwilam, have you solved this problem? I encountered same

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848877/generating-migration-file-for-a-project-using-nestjs-and-typeorm

Answer (score 15):

Try to change your entities dir in ormconfig.json or .env, it worked for me as:

```
"entities": ["dist/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue, how you are loading the `**TypeOrmModule**`. The way, you had loaded, it is synchronous so it simply means custom `env` will not be available instantly on application boot.

So what you can do, is to load  **TypeOrmModule**` asynchronusly like below -

```
 ConfigModule.forRoot({
  isGlobal: true, // [REQUIRED if want to use env gloablly among all modules]
 }),
 TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT, 10),
        username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
        synchronize: false,
        migrations: [process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS],
        cli: {
          migrationsDir: process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR,
        },
        logging: process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING === 'true' ? true : false,
        entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      }),
 }),
```

Answer (score -1):

You could specify the connection in `ormconfig.json` in the project root folder.

looking something like this

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": <port>,
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "",
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": "all",
    "migrations": [
        "migrations/**/*.js"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "subscriber/**/*.js"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "<migrations directory>",
        "subscribersDir": "<subscriber directory>"
    }
}
```

Read more in the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#creating-a-new-migration) chapter

On a side note, you might have to remove your *dist/* folder for changes to get through.